# Bootstrap datetimepicker setting date

Tags: bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker

I'm using the following code to set the date in a bootstrap datetimepicker (following an ajax call)

```js
$('#modalinputdate').datetimepicker({
    date: new Date(data.EVENTDATE)
});
```

The problem is when I run the code for a second time (a different ajax call) the date does not get set. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does your page refresh the content with the first ajax call?

Comment: try putting given code in the success of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your content is being refreshed/replaced along with your original ajax call. Try modifying or selecting a static parent element, like:

```
$("#youStaticAjaxContainer").find("#modalinputdate",function(e){
    e.datetimepicker({
          date: new Date(data.EVENTDATE)
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's still not working. The form itself (where the datepicker lives) is in a modal if that make a difference.

Comment: No, I wouldn't think so, not if it's  a static Bootstrap modal.   Do you only have an issue setting the value after the initial post? Are you able to read the value?

Comment: Yeah, it's only after the initial post. The first post works fine